# Adding new acces config on SSH Connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a problem on my Google Cloud Platform account In SSH connection, I can delete my existing access config but can not add new one. When I run the command below the screen is waiting and nothing is happening. However, in Cloud Shell, I did not encounter any problem, I can both delete existing access config and add new one.

Could you help me to add a new access config via ssh?

Command: gcloud compute instances add-access-config dev-instance --access-config-name "external-nat" --zone=us-west1-b

Comment: To my understanding it seems you are looking at running it from the SSH. However since the cloud shell is working, I would suggest you run from there. Please note by issuing the delete command you are actually removing your instance's external IP address and your SSH connection will be lost

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to run both add and delete commands from cloud shell because it is out of the  instance.

But you will not be able to add access config via SSH after deleting because, if you delete the existing access config it will remove the instance's external IP address  and your SSH connection will be lost. External-nat is used as the default if the flag --access-config-name value  is not provided. Since ONE_TO_ONE_NAT is currently the only access-config type, it is not recommended that you change this value.

For more information:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-access-config